# Dump remote MySQL database from a docker container

Tags: docker, pipe, mysql

I'm trying to dump a remote database into a local docker container's database.

```
$ docker exec -i my_container \
  mysqldump my_remote_database -h my_remote_host.me -u my_remote_user -p
```

This gives me the remote dump well

So here are my attempts:

```
$ docker exec -i my_container \
  mysqldump my_remote_database -h my_remote_host.me -u my_remote_user -p \
| docker exec -i my_container mysql -u my_local_user -pmy_local_password \
      -D my_local_database

$ docker exec -i my_container bash -c \
    "mysqldump my_remote_database -h my_remote_host.pp -u my_remote_user -p \
   | mysql -u my_local_user -pmy_local_password -D my_local_database"
```

Both don't seem to have any effect on the local database (no error though)

How can I transfer these data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always like to hammer out problems from inside the container in an interactive terminal.

First, get the cantainer of image running and check to see the following:

1. If you bash onto the local container `docker exec -ti my_container bash`, does the remote hostname `my_remote_host.me` resolve and can you route to it?  Use ping or nslookup.
2. From inside the interactive terminal bash shell can you connect to the remote db?  Just try a vanilla mysql cli connect using the credentials
3. Finally try the dump from inside the interactive terminal and just create a `mydump.sql` dump file.

Then check that inside the container:

1. You can connect to the local DB the credetials provided (if using tcp connection not socket the hostname should resolve, but it looks like your local db is using a socket)
2. See if you can load the dump file using `mysql -u my_local_user -pmy_local_password -D mylocaldb < mydump.sql`

If this all works then you can start looking at why the pipe is failing, but I suspect the issue may be with one of the resolutions.

I notice you say local database. Is the 'local database' inside the container or on the Docker host running a socket connection?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All the checks you are mentioning I did them already (the first 3 checks are actually covered in my question). I can then inject the dump with `mysql`. The issue seems indeed to be with the pipe.

Comment: My later attempt was in fact working. I was checking the content of destination database wrongly...

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY happens to everyone!